# element to animate on scroll up, reverse on scroll down

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to do something that I'm sure is quite simple...I'm slowly teaching myself JQuery, so I've been reading forums and Googling different terms all day, but I can't seem to make it happen!

I need the image of the sign to slide left (out of view) when the following div scrolls up (no problem)...but, I'd like the action to reverse when the user scrolls back down.

This fiddle achieves the initial animation: http://jsfiddle.net/fr2Sw/

I've tried a whole bunch of methods that aren't working...functions like this:

```
var canSee = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $("#box").animate({left:"-=200px"});
        canSee = true;
    } else if (!canSee) {
        $("#box").animate({left:"=0px"});
    }
});
```

Thank you so much, any help is much appreciated! If you don't mind, please explain what's happening in each function "in english" if you can :o)

Comment: Leave out the "=" in the else animate(). I think you can leave out the "px" part as well. Also, if the user is scrolling a lot > 100 then there might be a lot of += going on (I.e., the distance might be several hundred px)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var canSee = true;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100 && canSee) {
        $("#box").animate({left:"-=200px"});
        canSee = false;
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 100 && !canSee) {
        $("#box").animate({left:"+=200px"});
        canSee = true;
    }
});
```

Initialize casSee to true, because the user can see the image. When the user scrolls, do the following:

If the Windows's scrollTop is over 100 and the image is still visible, hide it by sliding it left out of the screen, so it only happens once--it will never scroll beyond 200px. When the user scrolls back up, if the image is out of the viewport and canSee is set to false, slide the image back in and set canSee to true, because the user can see it.

Comment: You're AMAZING!!!! For some reason, I didn't get email notifications of these responses. Gonna hafta fix that right now! Thank you so, so much. Now, did you make up the word 'canSee', or is that an actual specified variable (like .scrollTop, .animate...etc)?

Comment: @amandabeau You're welcome :) I declared `canSee` at the top as a variable initialized to `true`. It's just a regular old boolean, just named "canSee" to be helpful in understanding what it does. Also, the `.scrollTop` and `.animate` variable are what are known as *members* of an object, not variables like `canSee`. Additionally, `.scrollTop` and `.animate` are also referred to as *methods* (instead of functions) in an object-oriented context, such as this.

Comment: gotcha. I'm still having trouble understanding which parts of the scripts I'm allowed to declare, vs the parts that are actually legit methods/functions. My "teaching myself" is basically stealing sites I like, taking them apart, then trying to re-write to suit my needs. This community imparticular has been so helpful and friendly.

Comment: I think that's as valid a way to learn as any. My favorite method has always been to attack it from any perspective I can. Reading up about the basics while taking my favorite sites apart. The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com) (when it starts to seem less opaque to you) will be invaluable after a certain point--just google "jquery animate" for example. And it looks like @HugoLemos link would be a great place to master the basics if you want a more hands on approach

Answer (score 1):

If you want show the image only when the scroll is on the top, use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
            $("#box").animate({
                left: "0px"
            });
        } else if ($("#box").css("left") == "0px") {
            $("#box").animate({
                left: -$("#box").width()
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, this works and the animation seems to be smoother than the previous answer. However, it doesn't seem to work until the second time I scroll. Thoughts?? And, thank you!!!